# how to retrieve a value passed in the url through a gravity forms form field

Tags: parameter-passing

I have a button in html, I added a variable to its link and I want to retrieve it from gravity forms.

```
 <div>
 <a  href="/test/?test name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In gravity forms edit mode, click on the field you want to populate with the parameter.  Under the "advanced tab", click the "Allow Field to be Populated Dynamically" checkbox.

Add your url parameter, in this case, 'test_name'.

Make sure your url link looks something like this:
href="/test/?test_name=Mike"

Assuming your gravity form is embedded on the "test" page, you should see your field populated with the string, "Mike".